# LIME does not show the features' scores for positive class explanation

Tags: nlp, prediction, text-classification, lime, xai

i'm trying to explain the prediction for binary text classification model (LSTM&GRU using BERT embedding) with LIME, it highlights the features for both classes, but it shows the score for each feature just for class 0. even if i tried different text and num_samples. how can i know what is the problem? here is the code and pictures for the explanations.

## the explainer

explainer = LimeTextExplainer()

## Generate an explanation for a single instance

exp = explainer.explain_instance(text, predict_proba, num_features=7, num_samples=700)
exp.show_in_notebook(text = True)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkNSY.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKOkb.png)

i tried to explain the text classififcation prediction, and i expected to see the important features with its score, but the score did not show just for the positive class